# C# MySQL DataReader Boolean Value Toggle/CheckBox (metro ui)

Tags: c#, mysql, database

So I am creating a personal database editor using c# and metro ui.  And I do apologize as I am very very new to programming and just been learning bits from youtube and trying to put everything together.  Not the best code I believe, but it works for me.

What I am trying to do is to turn this toggle button on if the value is true.  Or have the checkbox "checked" if true.  I know it works becasue I tested and the value was actually written "true".  Any help would be greatly appericate, I can not seem to find the correct answer for this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MetroFramework.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LineageDB_Editor
{
    public partial class Form1 : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
    {

        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=l1jdb;Uid=root;Pwd=root");
        MySqlCommand command;
        MySqlDataReader mdr;

        public Form1()

        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void metroLabel7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void metroLabel22_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void metroTextBox6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void metroButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connection.Open();

            string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM armor WHERE item_id=" + int.Parse(metroTextBox6.Text);
            command = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);

            mdr = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (mdr.Read())
            {
                metroTextBox3.Text = mdr.GetString("name");
                metroTextBox4.Text = mdr.GetString("name_id");
                metroTextBox5.Text = mdr.GetInt32("itemdesc_id").ToString();
                metroTextBox17.Text = mdr.GetInt16("safenchant").ToString();
                metroTextBox18.Text = mdr.GetInt32("weight").ToString();
                metroTextBox19.Text = mdr.GetInt16("ac").ToString();
                metroTextBox13.Text = mdr.GetString("type");
                metroTextBox14.Text = mdr.GetInt16("acctype").ToString();
                metroTextBox15.Text = mdr.GetInt16("grade").ToString();
                metroTextBox16.Text = mdr.GetString("material");
                metroTextBox1.Text = mdr.GetInt16("invgfx").ToString();
                metroTextBox2.Text = mdr.GetInt16("grdgfx").ToString();
                metroTextBox7.Text = mdr.GetInt16("add_str").ToString();
                metroTextBox8.Text = mdr.GetInt16("add_con").ToString();
                metroTextBox11.Text = mdr.GetInt16("add_dex").ToString();
                metroTextBox9.Text = mdr.GetInt16("add_int").ToString();
                metroTextBox10.Text = mdr.GetInt16("add_wis").ToString();
                metroTextBox12.Text = mdr.GetInt16("add_cha").ToString();
                metroTextBox20.Text = mdr.GetInt16("defense_water").ToString();
                metroTextBox21.Text = mdr.GetInt16("defense_wind").ToString();
                metroTextBox22.Text = mdr.GetInt16("defense_fire").ToString();
                metroTextBox23.Text = mdr.GetInt16("defense_earth").ToString();
                metroTextBox24.Text = mdr.GetInt16("add_hp").ToString();
                metroTextBox25.Text = mdr.GetInt16("add_mp").ToString();
                metroTextBox26.Text = mdr.GetInt16("add_hpr").ToString();
                metroTextBox27.Text = mdr.GetInt16("add_mpr").ToString();
                metroTextBox28.Text = mdr.GetInt16("add_sp").ToString();
                metroTextBox29.Text = mdr.GetInt16("m_def").ToString();
                metroTextBox30.Text = mdr.GetInt16("regist_stun").ToString();
                metroTextBox31.Text = mdr.GetInt16("regist_stone").ToString();
                metroTextBox32.Text = mdr.GetInt16("regist_sleep").ToString();
                metroTextBox33.Text = mdr.GetInt16("regist_freeze").ToString();
                metroTextBox34.Text = mdr.GetInt16("regist_sustain").ToString();
                metroTextBox35.Text = mdr.GetInt16("regist_blind").ToString();
                metroTextBox36.Text = mdr.GetInt16("regist_DESPERADO").ToString();
                metroToggle1.Text = mdr.GetBoolean("use_royal").ToString();



            } 

        }



        private void metroLabel38_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never used MetroFramework, but MetroToggle is derived from Checkbox, so instead of setting its Text property, try doing metroToggle1.Checked = mdr.GetBoolean("use_royal") instead.

Comment: that works, thank you!